# Let $p=40k+9$ be prime. Does $10$ always have even order mod $p$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, quadratic-reciprocity, multiplicative-order

This came up while answering a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3826695/30402) on the period of the decimal expansion of $1/p$.  The critical factor was whether the period (aka the order of $10$ mod $p$) is even or odd, equivalently whether $-1$ is a power of $10$ mod $p$.

It’s easy to see that for some congruence classes of primes, the order is always even: if $(10/p) = -1$, then we explicitly have $10^{(p-1)/2} \equiv -1 \pmod p$.  In the other direction, if $(10/p) = +1$ but $(-1/p) =-1$, then clearly $-1$ cannot be a power of $10$.

This leaves only the case $(10/p) = (-1/p) = +1$, which amounts to 4 congruence classes mod $40$ where the parity is not trivially determined as above.  In 3 of those congruence classes, it was very straightforward to find primes whose parity is even and odd.  But for $9 \pmod{40}$, I only found even parities, at least for the first dozen primes.

Is there a reason for this phenomenon?  I know next to nothing about biquadratic reciprocity, but it surprises me if something can be said beyond quadratic reciprocity with purely modular constraints (as opposed to quadratic or higher polynomials).  Is this a small number effect owing to the relatively high power of $2$ dividing $p-1$?  Did I just make a simple miscalculation somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By brute force, $1/1609$ gives a repetend period of $201$.

We note that if the Euler totient function is a multiple of $2^k$ then $10$ has to be a $2^k$ power residue in order to make the repetend odd.  Because $10$ is always a quadratic residue, this has probability $1/2^{k-1}$ where $k=3$ for half of the relevant primes, $k=4$ for one quarter, $k=5$ for one eighth, etc., giveng the total probability

$(1/4)(1/2)+(1/8)(1/4)+(1/16)(1/8)+...=\color{blue}{1/6}$

The number of primes you need to try in order to get a success is thus predicted to be exponentially distributed with mean $6$.   The actual count is $18$, which had about a 5% chance of being that large given the predicted exponential distribution.  The issue in finding a prime was one of simple probability rather anything more profound.

Another answer notes that with 2000+ primes almost exactly one-sixth of them are successes.  Thus with enough statistical data we get what we should have expected all along.

Comment: Thank you for addressing my follow-up question; I gave you $+1$ as well

Comment: So simple :-) +1 was there earlier already.

Comment: Thanks for this analysis! (and thanks @J.W.Tanner for prompting the discussion).  Of the 4 residues I considered, 2 of them (13 and 37) have one less power of two in their multiplicative group, so the odd:even ratio is a more balanced 1:2.  So it was really only the one residue 1 mod 40 that was lucky to get both parities in the first two primes.  Both factors conspired to make 9 look unusually unlucky by comparison, but not statistically significant in itself.

Answer (score 4):

There are $2090$ primes $\equiv 9 \mod 40$ less than or equal $400009$.  Of these,
there are $323$ for which the order of $10$ is odd, the first being $1609$.

Comment: $+1$; is there a heuristic explanation why not so many are odd?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I'm not sure, but I am thinking about the following. If $p\equiv9\pmod{40}$, then $p-1$ is a multiple of $8$. The group $\Bbb{Z}_p^*$ is cyclic of order $p-1$. So for $10$ to have an odd order, it has to be an eighth power modulo $p$. You automatically made it a quadratic residue, but that leaves still significant extra. Also, if $p\equiv49\pmod{80}$ then $16\mid p-1$ et cetera.

Comment: Hmm. Erick said pretty much the same thing in the last paragraph :-/

Comment: @jwtanner see my answer. 323/2090 is well within the expected range for successes.

Comment: Thanks all for the interesting discussion